# ios - filter two arrays with objects Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter

I have got two `arrays` with objects.

```
var filteredData:[MainData] = [MainData]()
var removeData:[MainData] = [MainData]()

struct MainData {
    var open:NSTimeInterval
    var works = [Visit]()
}
```

I want remove data from `filteredData` using function `filter` with parameter filteredData.open == removeData.open

I can't filter two arrays with objects.

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this, first get an `Array` of open from `removeData` array and check that it is contains object from the `filteredData` Array opens.

```
let opens = removeData.map { $0.open }
filteredData = filteredData.filter { !opens.contains($0.open) }
```